# Add Files from google sheets to google drive folder by other user without giving editor rights to other user

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that can add file from google sheet to a folder in my drive but if other user needs to upload then I need to give editor rights of that folder to that user. Is there any way so that the file can upload without giving editor rights?

Please help.

App script Code

```
     function openAttachmentDialog() {
         var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('UploadFile');
         SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
         .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
        }
        function saveFile(obj) {
         var blob = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(obj.data), obj.mimeType, obj.fileName);
         var file = DriveApp.getFolderById("18bws1zMXcvTrur9Y30QisZQzXuRqTrWd").createFile(blob);
         var cellFormula = file.getUrl();
         
         evcssheet.getRange('F1').setValue(cellFormula);
         
         return file.getId();
        }
```

HTML Code

````
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <base target="_top">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
          </head>
          <script>
            function getFiles() {
              document.getElementById("uploadButton").disabled = true;
              const progressText = document.getElementById("progress");
              const f = document.getElementById('files');
              var uploadCompletedCount = 0;
              progressText.innerHTML = "Uploading file " + (uploadCompletedCount + 1) + "/" + [...f.files].length + "";
              [...f.files].forEach((file, i) => {
                const fr = new FileReader();
                fr.onload = (e) => {
                  const data = e.target.result.split(",");
                  const obj = {fileName: f.files[i].name, mimeType: data[0].match(/:(\w.+);/)[1], data: data[1]};
                  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((id) => {
                    uploadCompletedCount++;
                    progressText.innerHTML = "Upload completed";
                    if (uploadCompletedCount >= [...f.files].length){
                      google.script.host.close();
                    }
                    else{
                      progressText.innerHTML = "Uploading file " + (uploadCompletedCount + 1) + "/" + [...f.files].length + "";
                    }
                  }).saveFile(obj);
                }
                fr.readAsDataURL(file);
              });
            }
          </script>
          <body>
            <!-- <input type="file" name="upload" id="files" multiple/> -->
            <input type="file" name="upload" id="files"/> <!-- I expect to up load only one file -->
            <input type='button' id="uploadButton" value='Upload' onclick='getFiles()' class="action"> 
            <br><br>
            <div id="progress"> </div>
          </body>
        </html>
    
    ```
````

Comment: About `I have a script that can add file from google sheet to a folder in my drive`, can you provide your current script?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You tagged `flysystem-google-drive` (which is presumably as variation on the 'flysystem' PHP abstraction layer for filesystems). And you also tagged `google-apps-script` and `javascript` as well as `html`. Which of these (if any) is your preference for a solution?

Comment: @Tanaike I have provided the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your script, in your script, it seems that each user runs the script for uploading the file as each user. In this case, your folder is required to be shared with each user. So, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose using Web Apps for uploading the file to the folder in your Google Drive. By this, when the user uploads the file, the file can be uploaded as you (owner of the script). If this was not included in your expected direction, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the reply. But users are uploading from google sheet like they need to put some data in google sheet then he or she needs to upload the file from the same sheet, so I can not provide them the web app solution. Is there any way like using property service or something to manipulate the owner of the file, kindly let me know if there are. But anyway thanks for the reply

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comments were not useful for your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike no need to mention, I appreciate your help.